# Optimized way to apply a function on lists of list

Tags: python, list

I have a script which is very fast, but just one line is slow. I don't will copy paste all the script because it's very long, but the line which take time is the following:

```
PF, PJ, PR = [pertes_etats(pertes, n) for pertes in (PF, PJ, PR)]
```

PF,PJ and PR are list of lists of two elements. The first element of the sublists an integer and the second a list.
Exemple of a sublist of PF:sublist=[3,[2,1,4,2,1,9...,1]]

Here is the function pertes_etas

```
def pertes_etats(P, n):
    if not P:
        return np.ones(n)
    else:
        return np.sum([x[0]*np.array(x[1]) for x in P], axis=0)
```

Exemple: PR=[[1,[1,2,3]],[3,[4,5,6]]]

Then you must obtain `[1*1+3*4,1*2+3*5,1*3+3*6]=[13,17,21]`

I think the function pertes_etats is already good optimized but I'm not sure I apply it the better way.
Any idea to accelerate the code?

Comment: If the first element of  `P` is an `int` how can you use `x[0]`?

Comment: @PabloC the first element in PF is an int, P is a tuple [PF, PR, PR]

Comment: You call your function three times, first with `PF`, then with `PJ` and finally with `PR`

Comment: jmmm you're right, I have a question: could you show some values (toy example) and the expected output?

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry, I edited

Comment: Can you somehow change how you construct your input? You compute `A*x`. But you store `A` and `x` in a not convenient way. If  `x = np.array([[p for p, _ in P]])` and 
`A = np.array([c for _, c in P])` the multiplication `x.dot(A)` is much faster. But rebuilding data consumes most of time. So to get the benefit from `numpy` you should change data construction somewhere early in your code.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize the execution time of this code you can always run it in parallel:

```py
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

items = [pertes for pertes in (PF, PJ, PR)]

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=min(multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
                                          len(items)))
try:
    pool_results = pool.map(
        func=partial(pertes_etats,n=n),
        iterable=items,
    )

finally:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

PF, PJ, PR = pool_results
```

It will parallelize by the amount of items there are in `items`, in this case 3. The `min()` is used to control the maximum of processes are created, if you created more processes than elements in items it will create empty processes which can create undesirable behavior or even make it to crash.